# Android: How can i change the Build Target of one class

Tags: android

I have a project with Build Target Android 2.1 and i want to use Google map in it.
I know that to use the Google map i should create a project with Built Target Google APIs.
I want to extend MapActivity in one class not for all the project.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have one question: Google Map is a option in your app. or permanent feature?
In the first case I think you can encaplusate you code for Google Map in external jar.
In the second case I should change to GoogleApi(Android 2.1)